# Up button with multiple possible parents that can be further back in the activity stack

Tags: android

I'm having a problem deciding how to handle the UP button.

Activity C and D are two ways to view downloaded material.
Activity B is to select among already downloaded material.
Activity A is the starting activity, and the one where material is selected for download.

A stack could look like these:

A, B, C, D

A, B, D, C

A, B, C

A, B, D

And the stack could look the same sans B:

A, C, D

A, D, C

A, C

A, D

The parent of B is obviously A:
Parent(B) = A

The parent for C an D however is more tricky. I think a user would assume they would return to select another already downloaded material if that was what they were doing beforehand. Otherwise they would assume they would return to the start of the app:
Parent(C) = Parent(D) = "B if it exists in the stack; A otherwise"

Two problems:

1) It seems like the official Android guides on navigation only consider the possibility that an activity has one single activity as parent.

2) I have not been able to figure out an elegant way to accomplish this (which supports problem 1). However I've considered solution a and b:

a) Making every activity pop to the parent through a chain of onNewIntent until the onNewIntent of A or B stops it. Whichever comes first.

b) Having a static stack structure onto which parents are pushed and popped so that a C or D activity can go to A or B directly. Whichever is on the top of the parent stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose a third solution:

I have an extra called parentString in C and D. A and B gives the appropriate parentString to C and D when starting them. C and D pass it along to the other. When the up button is selected in C and D parentString is used to determine what activity to pop back to.

I use the activities' class.toString as parentString.